# How can I edit the WooCommerce Mini DropDown Cart to read as follows

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

Currently, this code returns "Quantity x Price"... so e.g. 2 x £3.00

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
```

But I want it to return either "Quantity x the word Quote"... so e.g. 2 x Quote.

Or... "Quantity: 2"

Could you advise how I should alter this code to achieve either of these two outcomes?

Many thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function and filter hook

```
function filter_woo_cart_quantity($output, $cart_item, $cart_item_key){
        return '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; Quote', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</span>';
    }
add_filter('woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity','filter_woo_cart_quantity',10, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That doesn't seem to work. It just returns "1" and nothing else.

Comment: I updated the code. Check now. If it doesn't work try changing  the number `10` to a bigger value than 10

Comment: I appreciate the help Karun, but it's not working. It just returns a 1 no matter what number I replace 10 with.

Comment: What about option 2... i.e. just returning Quantity = 2 (or whatever number of that product you have in your cart).

Comment: The method is same. The function should have worked.